# How to Send Instance from Main Windows to User Control

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

Goal:
Reduce tight coupling and increase loose coupling for user control 1 and 2.

Problem:
Is it possible to send some instance from main windows to user control 1 and 2?
If yes, do you have a example or recommended link about it?

Information:
- I'm using VS 2013

[image]

Xaml code:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:usercontrol_menu="clr-namespace:usercontrol_menu;assembly=usercontrol_menu" xmlns:usercontrol_kassa="clr-namespace:usercontrol_kassa;assembly=usercontrol_kassa" x:Class="main_system.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="900" Width="1300         ">
    <Grid>
        <Frame x:Name="mainFrame"/>
        <ContentControl x:Name="cc_content" Content="ContentControl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="482,144,-228,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="298" Width="1038"/>
        <usercontrol_menu:UserControl1 HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <usercontrol_kassa:UserControl1 HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,344,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Not from XAML that I know of.  If you create the control in code behind then you can pass a reference to the main window in the ctor.

Comment: Do you have any concrete example that you can display please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass a reference in the ctor

```
namespace UserControlPassReference
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            UserControl1 uc1 = new UserControl1(this);
        }
    }
}

namespace UserControlPassReference
{
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        private Window main;
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public UserControl1(Window Main)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            main = Main;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the `Window.GetWindow` Method.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.getwindow(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.getwindow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var wnd = Window.GetWindow(this); //Assuming this is a user control (or any DependencyObject).
```

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515124/whats-the-simplest-ioc-container-for-c)

You also can be interested in [PRISM](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/)

So, once you have IoC container, you can pass it to all your UserControls (via ViewModels, or something else), and using it you can get access to anything you have registered in it.